# Using .Net backend for Android and IOS apps

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, sqlite

I'm able to create MVC5 .Net applications for the web. I just need clarification on how I can proceed with developing Android and IOS apps. I was considering Xamarin, but I've decided to go with Android(Java) and Swift. My question is can I use .Net MVC5 with the mobile platforms for the backend?

AND followup question and this might be dumb, but I"m just not sure, If the answer is no to my first question, then if I were to learn to use SQLite to push data to database, can I push it to same database that was initially created with .Net MVC5 if the database was hosted on a server or would that database be restricted to being manipulated with the .Net Web API only? Basically can I use .Net and SQLite on the same database, but different platforms?

Comment: For a mobile application, it does not matter how is your backend implemented. The only thing that it'll need is an API through which it'll communicate to your backend. This API can be developed in any language. Secondly, SQLite itself is a database like MySQL, MSSQL, etc. so you can not use it to push data to some other database.

Comment: Applications communicate between each other using a protocol. So long as the protocol you choose to communicate with is available on both platforms, you can use whatever you want. That's why technology stack agnostic protocols like serving JSON over HTTP are so popular.